# Including code test coverage of classes that are not in the same module with Jacoco

Tags: maven, code-coverage, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am working on getting code test coverage of a large project with multiple modules. I am looking to do this with Jacoco, and I have it working for almost each individual module. The issue comes about when I want to tie one of the modules, which is mainly a library, to the coverage reports of the other modules. For example, here's what part of our project looks like:

```
MAIN-LIBRARY
---<collection of library modules, not many tests in here>
LARGE-MODULE
---<collection of some modules, contains a large amount of integration tests>
```

These are 2 separate directories both within one parent directory.

The large module calls the library module quite a bit. What I'm currently trying to do is to get jacoco to recognize when classes in Main Library have been hit by the tests in Large-Module, and include those in the report for Large-Module. I have looked all over and have not found much. I have tried using `<include>${project.basedir}/../MAIN-LIBRARY/path/to/classes/*.class</include>` within my pom file for the Large-Module, but that just makes nothing show up in the report. Any pointers? Is this even possible with Jacoco? Am I not using the include correctly? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution?